# Cloud Platforms- sudo: unable to resolve host

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sudo, openstack

I use linux for my cloud based servers on Amazon-EC2 and openstack.
When trying to run:

```
sudo chhown ubuntu somepath
```

I get this error every once in a while:

> sudo: unable to resolve host

Most answers to this question on the internet are to edit the /etc/hosts file.

However, I deploy my servers automatically. besides that, I am not logging on using "localhost", but rather my AWS public DNS:

```
ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@ec2-12-34-56-78.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

So I cannot just trivially insert localhost, not to mention that my IP can change after I reset my machine. (Don't want to "waste" my precious floating IPs for every server)

Also, I deploy tens of servers at a time, so I cannot afford the manual step of editing a text file. Is there an automated fix for this issue?
Recently I've started using openstack, and the issue is present there too.

Comment: how about `sudo -s; chown ubuntu somepath`? any error?

Comment: Same error: unable to resolve hist SOME_DNS .Strange, this time I was unable to re-create it from AWS. But it consistantly manifested in openstack. I have noticed that while I ssh to an IP, the shell prompt is: ubuntu@SOME_DNS . SOME_DNS is the internal server name so i cannot ssh to it from the outside.

Comment: from outside, you need use public ip

Comment: In this case (openstack), I did use a public IP (otherwise SSH would not have worked). But when I am already logged on, the prompt shows the hostname. With AWS I also have a public host-name, but that is not the case this time around.

Comment: When you type your command, your terminal displays : `username@yourservername:~$ sudo chhown ubuntu somepath`. To fix this issue, you could try to add the line `127.0.0.1 yourservername` to the file `/etc/hosts`. Works for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

EC2 instances inside VPC will resolve their auto-assigned internal hostnames correctly, only if you configure the VPC correctly.   You need:

```
DNS hostnames: yes
DNS resolution: yes
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html

Comment: Looks reasonable, I can't duplicate the error in my environment, then can't judge this answer. Wait for OP's feedback.

Comment: Thanks, Any idea about Openstack?

Comment: wow, I've been wondering how to properly do this for a while. Great pro tip!

Comment: I have the same issue, I have tried this but it still doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @user1775671 if you have configured a domain suffix in your dhcp settings for the VPC, this will also happen if the records aren't in DNS.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Can you elaborate on that? What records need to be in DNS? I'm trying to understand my company's AWS setup and I think what you're describing might be the problem

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this problem I ran the following commands:

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

Then in the hosts file that opens up add:

```
127.0.0.1     10.0.30.150
```

Obviously the `10.0.30.150` address would be the IP of the host in the warning message.